# Set a leaning separation between two divs

Tags: html, css

i'm currently trying to create a landing page for a mobile website, and I want two main divs with an image on it. (In my example there are colors). Here is my HTML :

```
<ion-content>

  <div class="upperblock"></div>
  <div class="downblock"></div>

</ion-content>
```

My CSS :

```
  .upperblock{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #2ec95c;


  }

  .downblock{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: #000;

  }
```

I would like to have a "leaning" separation, something like that (the screenshot of my result, and the red line is where I'd like the separation to be ):

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help, couldn't find anything about this !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2ec95c;
}
.upperblock {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #2ec95c;
  color: #000;
}

.downblock {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}

.block {
  transform: skewY(-6deg);
  padding: 50px;
  margin: -5% 0;
}
.block * {
  transform: skewY(6deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block upperblock">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="block downblock">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fkg love you man. this thing had me exhausted

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add another div down below each div (I think `:after` should do the trick here) and then turn it with `transform: rotate(15deg)`. This will turn the div.

Important note: Content in the turned box will be also turned. So you may want to seperate the content and background div.

Other way would be to create a svg image. SVG will scale perfectly and the code will look way cleaner ;)

Comment: And it is important to set parent to relative and "after" to absolute

Answer (score 1):

You can also use pseudo-elements to achieve that

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.upperblock {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #2ec95c;
  position: relative;
}

.downblock {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.downblock::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: skewY(-5deg) translateY(-65%);
}
```

```html
<div class="upperblock"></div>
<div class="downblock"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append a block to the `upperblock` div using CSS and rotate that using `transform`. You'll need to play with the heights depending on your content but this will expand and be responsive.

```css
.outer {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.upperblock{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 40vh;
  background-color: #2ec95c;
  position: relative;
}
.upperblock::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 120px;
  background: #2ec95c;
  width: calc(100% + 50px);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -60px;
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}

.downblock{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60vh;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="upperblock"></div>
  <div class="downblock"></div>
</div>
```